# How to properly dispatch variable through Redux action / reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to pass my isMatched variable through my action and conditionally change the boolean value based on the json response sent from the post route.

However, my current setup always returns a payload of undefined. What am I missing here within this to successfully change my values based on the data?

```js
    onSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();


      const resetPassword = {
        email: this.username,
        password: this.state.password,
        password2: this.state.password2,
        isMatched: false
      };

      this.props.updateUserPassword(resetPassword);

    };



    // Reset Password action to dispatch isMatched to reducer

    export const updateUserPassword = resetPassword => dispatch => {
     axios
      .post("/api/users/resetpassword", resetPassword)
      .then(res => {

      if (res.data.msg === 'passwords match') {

        const isMatched = true;

        dispatch(setMatchedPass(isMatched));

      } else {

        const isMatched = false;

      }
    })
    };

    // Matched Password Dispatch
    export const setMatchedPass = isMatched => {
     return {
       type: SET_MATCH_PASS,
       payload: isMatched
       ***** If I set this to 'testing', that's output, but if *****
       ***** I try to dispatch the variable isMatched, it doesn't *****
       ***** seem to pass the value. *****
     };
    };


    // Matched Password Reducer

    import { SET_MATCH_PASS } from "../actions/types";

    const matchedState = {
      isMatched: false
    };

    export default function (state = matchedState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

      case SET_MATCH_PASS:
        return {
          ...state,
          isMatched: action.payload
        };
      default:
        return state;

     } 

    }
```

EDIT: Defining resetPassword to pass values to updateUserPassword

```
/* Connect Mapstate to props */
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateUserPassword })(ResetPassword);
```

```js
      onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();


        const resetPassword = {
          email: this.username,
          password: this.state.password,
          password2: this.state.password2,
          isMatched: false
        };

        this.props.updateUserPassword(resetPassword);

      };


    // This takes resetPassword, sets isMatched and dispatches it to setMatchedPass


    export const updateUserPassword = resetPassword => dispatch => {
      axios
        .post("/api/users/resetpassword", resetPassword)
        .then(res => {

          const isMatched = true;
          dispatch(setMatchedPass(isMatched));

        })
        .catch(err =>
          dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
          })
        );



    //** To pass isMatched through type SET_MATCH_PASS

    export const setMatchedPass = isMatched => {

      console.log('setting isMatched for SET_MATCH_PASS action:', isMatched);

      return {
        type: SET_MATCH_PASS,
        payload: isMatched
      };

    };


    //** MatchReducer to receive the isMatched property and change the 
    //** state of isMatched in Store

    import { SET_MATCH_PASS } from "../actions/types";

    const matchedState = {
      isMatched: false
    };

    export default function (state = matchedState, action) {

      switch (action.type) {

        case SET_MATCH_PASS:
          return {
            ...state,
            isMatched: action.payload
          };
        default:
          return state;

      }

    }



     //// **** TO RENDER THE COMPONENT **** ////


    const MatchedComp = ({ isMatched }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {isMatched && <div>If you see this, the password is correct</div>}
        </div>
      );

    };

    MatchedComp.propTypes = {
      isMatched: PropTypes.bool,
    };



    /// This is called in my return ///
    <MatchedComp {...this.props} />



    //** Mapping props / state **//
    const mapStateToProps = state => {

      console.log(state);
      return {
        auth: state.auth,
        errors: state.errors,
        isMatched: state.isMatched
      }
    };


    ////*** OUTPUT OF console.log(state); ***////


    {auth: {…}, match: {…}, errors: {…}}
     auth: {
       isAuthenticated: false, 
       user: {…}, 
       loading: false
     }
     errors: {}
     match:
      isMatched: true
    __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object


    // *** Output of {console.log('in render', isMatched)} *** ///

    **in render undefined**
```

Comment: I'm curious to see what's the output of `console.log(action)` in reducer when you dispatch `SET_MATCH_PASS`, do you actually see {type: SET_MATCH_PASS , payload: undefined} ?

Comment: @Uma if I do a console.log(setMatchedPass()); in my onSubmit handler, it results in {type: "SET_MATCH_PASS", payload: undefined}

Comment: In setMatchedPass method console have data or it's showing undefined?

Comment: how your retrieved data into redux..use useSelector() concept it's easy to get data from redux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to debug without having the whole picture. But make sure that the `type` you use is the same in actions and reducer.

To see how data travels and where it breaks.

```
// Matched Password Dispatch
export const setMatchedPass = isMatched => {
 console.log('setting isMatched for SET_MATCH_PASS action: ', isMatched, SET_MATCH_PASS);
 return {
   type: SET_MATCH_PASS, // make sure this type is the same as in reducer
   payload: isMatched
 };
};
```

Then check in reducer you - both the action and payload:

```
export default function (state = matchedState, action) {
     console.log('Checking again', action.type, action.payload);
     switch (action.type) {
          case SET_MATCH_PASS:
               ...
          default:
     return state;

     }
}
```

EDIT (Update based on your `state` console log): to show how to retrieve value from redux

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const MyComponent = ({
  isMatched
}) => {
  /**
   * It will re-render each time the value of `isMatched` is changed
   */
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log('in render', isMatched) // what value do you see here?}
      {isMatched && <div>If you see this, the password is correct</div>}
    </div>

  );
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  isMatched: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // your value on state is stored in `match` 
  return {
    isMatched: state.match.isMatched,
  }
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Both of those result in the expected output. This means that something is wrong after it's returning, correct? Here's the output of the console.logs ---- setting isMatched for SET_MATCH_PASS action:  true SET_MATCH_PASS
----- Checking again SET_MATCH_PASS true

Comment: Yes, it seems that data sets correctly. Do you mind to show some code how you are getting `isMatched` in component and use it? Also in your previous comment you said you log `console.log(setMatchedPass());` - which will correctly return undefined, since you do not pass boolean in `setMatchedPass

Comment: Sorry, I suppose my question should be amended to how to properly return the value of a dispatched variable within the component. Now that we know the dispatch is working properly my error seems to be in actually retrieving the value from the store in my component. So, that being said, could you provide some example of how to render a value from the redux store?

Comment: @SethSpivey ok I edited my answer with sample component that uses the redux store value, let me know if you have questions

Comment: sorry I had to focus on other projects for the last couple of days. I've just gotten this implemented. However, it's resulting in an error of *** 'CustomizationStep' is not defined ***

Comment: oh my bad)) I messed up the naming in the example, it should be working now. Well kind of working, since you still need to update the part with `nameOfTheReducer` so it access the variable correctly

Comment: I've gotten this all set in the code without errors, however the rendering of the component isn't happening. I'm using <MatchedComp {...this.props} /> to try and pass the output inside the return and it's simply not rendering anything. I've got the state being console logged and isMatched is returning true from the state. Any ideas here?

Comment: do you mind to post code of the component where you are calling `updateUserPassword ` and setting "isMatched", and where you are trying to render `MyComponent`? as well as a name of the reducer where you are getting this variable in the state?

Comment: also do you mind to post the whole output of `console.log(state)`? I can only assume the part with `nameOfTheReducer` was not renamed correctly

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code you asked for! Let me know if there's anything else I can provide you to help understand this

Comment: @SethSpivey I updated my response with value based on your `state`. Let me know if that works now

Answer (score 4):

In your `mapStateToProps` you're accessing `state.isMatched` but you should use `state.match.isMatched` as shown in your logged `state`.

Comment: {console.log('in render', isMatched)} still returns " in render undefined " after making that edit

Comment: It seems some of your code is missing so it can't be diagnosed. For instance, you showed your `mapStateToProps` code, but not your `connect(...)` code. Other areas where it may go wrong is between what you export and what you import. You can `connect` and still use the unconnected component by accident, for instance (if exported). This would lead to the props being undefined as it is `connect` that normally sets those.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the connect. I believe I'll need to map the MatchedComp to props and export it, but I'm not quite sure how to do two exports from this. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see at the first look (although the code looks incomplete so maybe you already have it), but there is no `bindActionCreator` call happening on the component in the `connect` HOC. In simpler terms, you need to pass either an object with your actions to the second param of the `connect` call, something like this:

---

Component.js

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateUserPassword } from 'actions'; 

const Component = () => {
  // component code
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();


    const resetPassword = {
      email: this.username,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2,
      isMatched: false
    };

    this.props.updateUserPassword(resetPassword);

  };
}


// **The second argument is what you missed, I think.**

connect(mapStateToProps, {
  updateUserPassword: updateUserPassword,
})(Component)
```

---

actions.js

```js
export const updateUserPassword = resetPassword => dispatch => {
 axios
  .post("/api/users/resetpassword", resetPassword)
  .then(res => {

  if (res.data.msg === 'passwords match') {

    const isMatched = true;

    dispatch(setMatchedPass(isMatched));

  } else {

    const isMatched = false;

  }
})
};
```

It should work then.

Comment: You're somewhat right here. The error seems to be in my connect, however I'm need to do it like this. Right now, this only runs for one either ResetPassword OR MatchedComp. Here's the connect ----- export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, { updateUserPassword }
)(MatchedComp, ResetPassword);

Comment: In whichever component you might need to use the action, you'll need to always bind it to that component. So if you want it for both the components, both of them should be connected. Basically, `export default connect( mapStateToProps, { updateUserPassword } )(MatchedComp);` and `export default connect( mapStateToProps, { updateUserPassword } )(ResetPassword);` You can't pass two components to connect at once. Perhaps this will make it more clear to you: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-returns

Comment: And this might help you understand with examples and give you insight into why you were facing problems: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#example-usage

Comment: After looking through that I'm still having issues understanding how to properly do this. Is it possible to do what I'm wanting or do I need to try and work through it a different way?

Answer (score 0):

What did you use to handle async updateUserPassword action? For example:redux-thunk,redux-saga

Comment: I'm using redux-thunk

Comment: Thanks. Done!! You should update the updateUserPassword action. readmore here https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I finally cracked the export default connect of multiple components. As the answers before suggest, you can't export more than one connect per component, so I removed everything to do with MatchedComp and the rendering and stored it in another file with the following code:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const MatchedComp = ({ isMatched }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log('in render: ', isMatched)}
      {isMatched && <div>If you see this, the password is correct</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

MatchedComp.propTypes = {
  isMatched: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isMatched: state.match.isMatched,
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MatchedComp);
```

I then imported the MatchedComp into my ResetPassword file.

```
import MatchedComp from "../../components/auth/MatchedPassword";
```